# OpenCSV - Map multiple CSV columns to single bean attribute

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I have a requirement to,

1. combine two CSV columns into one bean attribute.
2. Perform a simple mathematical operation on a column value and map to bean attribute.

Wondering if something like this is possible using OpenCSV annotations.

**Input CSV**

```
User ID, First Name, Last Name, Worked Minutes
1234,Jon,Snow,60
1235,Rob,Stark,30
```

**Bean**

```
public class Employee {

  @CsvBindByName(column = "Employee ID")
  private String userId;

  //this should be "First Name, Last Name"
  private String employeeName;

  //this should be Worked Minutes/60
  private String workedHours;

  //getters and setters

}
```

The only way I have managed to do this is by mapping the columns as it is to separate attributes (`userId`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `workedMinutes`) and then modifying the `employeeName` and `workedHours` getter methods, but I feel like there should be a better way to do this.

Comment: Did you work this out?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this with OpenCSV, but there is a library I wrote called [jflat-core](https://github.com/algorythmist/jflat-core) that can handle such complex mappings between objects and flat files.

```
        CSVReader<Employee> csvReader = CSVReader
                .createWithHeaderMapping(Employee.class,
                        new String[] {"User ID", "First Name", "Last Name", "Worked Minutes"},
                        new String[] {"userId", "firstName", "lastName", "workedHours" });
        //register a special converter for the property workedHours
        csvReader.registerConverter("workedHours",
                minutes -> String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(minutes)/60.0));
        List<Employee> employees = csvReader.readAllWithCallback("employees.csv",
                //The callback can be used to help map attributes from the raw record to the target bean
                (record, employee) -> {
                    String name = String.format("%s %s", record.get("First Name"), record.get("Last Name"));
                    employee.setEmployeeName(name);
                });
        assertEquals(2, employees.size());
        assertEquals("Jon Snow", employees.get(0).getEmployeeName());
        assertEquals("0.5", employees.get(1).getWorkedHours());
```